# Allow anyone to upload images on a single Google Drive folder

Tags: google-drive

I had a function and many people took photographs. Is it possible to create a folder that anyone can edit and all the people can upload the pics they have in that folder?

Comment: Do you only want to use the folder to organize the photos or do you also want to take the ownership of them?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Share the folder, and go into Advanced.   Choose either public on the web or anyone-with-the-link, and then set the value to Can edit.

Comment: The response by MaryC.fromNZ only works if people have a Google account. Anonymous users can view, but not upload to a Google Drive folder.